# Given a projection matrix, how can I get the field of view angle in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, opengl-compat

With the function

```
void gluPerspective(GLdouble fovy,  GLdouble aspect,  GLdouble zNear,  GLdouble zFar);
```

I am able to set the perspective projection matrix according to a certain field of view angle.
Given a projection matrix, how can I get the field of view angle in OpenGL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [gluPersperctive](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml)

In the matrix you see `M[1][1] = f` and `f=cotang(fov/2) = 1 / tan(fov/2)`

So just pick the element at [1][1] and then `fov = 2·acotan(1/f)`

Comment: Thanks! I assume acotan(x) = arctan(x)?

Comment: `acotan(x) = arctan(x)`? Yes

Answer (score 0):

For Windows and DirectX it is:

[image]